# What happens when you use Robocopy between two remote computers on your WAN?

Tags: networking, windows-explorer, file-transfer, file-management, robocopy

Some details: I have a local server at one of the branches of the company I work for that has some pretty bad internet. I am using Robocopy to move some big files to the server once then using it again to move the files to several other computers at said branch over the local network. That brings me to my question...

Does robocopy.exe know to just send the data directly from the server to the machines UNC paths or does it (or some of it) bounce back to me first? Would it be faster to run the script from the branch server instead of my desktop? Would it make any difference?

Also I would be curious to know about the same situation if I did this manually with file explorer.

Powershell script I wrote to do the transfer. The file in question is ~3gb.

```
    $params1 = @(                                                                      
    "\\Remoteserver\C$\sourcefolder",                                                
    "\\Remotecomputer\C$\Users\someuser\Desktop",
    "file_Moved.iso",
    "/ipg:25")
    robocopy $params1 | Write-Host
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether you use robocopy of Windows Explorer doesn't matter. The computer you run the command on always acts as middle-man in the transfer and all traffic passes through that computer.

So yes: It would be much more efficient to push the files from the remote server to the remote clients. That way all traffic stays on the remote site.